# Azure AD B2C External User login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I was exploring Azure AD B2c feature to use in my application. Regarding this I have a query.
Suppose my email address is sheldoncooper@warnerbros.com. But I haven't used this email address in
any of the social media platforms. In this case how an end user will be able to login into the application?

Answer (score 0):

You can allow *local user signup* in the Azure AD B2C user flow.
The user will be required to create a password on registration.
Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-local?pivots=b2c-user-flow